# Azure powershell task on linux build agent throws The current operating system is not capable of running this task

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am using linux build agent to run azure powershell task for deployment.
When the task gets executed I get following error

"The current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only. For example, written for Windows Desktop PowerShell."

I get the same error even when I reduce the script down to print just "hello world".

My impression was that "Azure powershell task" is cross platform. But that's not what the error says or at least that's what I can interpret.

Any ideas what this issue is, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure PowerShell task in VSTS does not support PowerShell core currently. It is being worked on as per this issue - https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9201

Comment: I went by the docs, think they are bit misleading. Thanks Sam Cogan